# Loop para tornar edits invisiveis

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Tenho a seguinte maneira, para tornar os edits invisíveis.

```
edt_raster5.visible := false;
edt_raster6.visible := false;
edt_raster7.visible := false;
edt_raster8.visible := false;
edt_raster9.visible := false;
```

Existe uma maneira de usar um loop para tornar isso mais facil?
Sei que é bem simples mas não estou conseguindo acertar...tentei da seguinte mas claramente não deu certo.

```
for i := 1 to 9

edt_raster[i].visible := false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode varrer a propriedade `Components` do seu Form aonde fica armazenado todos os componentes dele e verificar quais são Edit para alterar.
Exemplo:

```
  for I := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Form1.Components[I] is TEdit then
    TEdit(Form1.Components[i]).Visible = false;
  end;
```

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas não queria tornar todos os edits invisiveis, somente os que possuíam um certo name.

Comment: Entendi, então utilize o método que voce postou, ou poderia varrer todos componentes, pegar todos edit, e checar o nome.

Comment: Sim, ja funcionou, mas tentei fazer a mesma coisa do checkbox, ele da erro de leitura...ainda não descobri o por que.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i := 1 to 9 do
    begin
    TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Visible := false;
    end;
```

Reslvou meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

geralmente trabalho dessa forma

```
for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do     // percore todos os componentes do form
    begin
       if Components[I] is TEdit then   // se for TEdit
          begin
              if (TEdit(Components[i]).name = 'edtDescricao') then  // se o componente for igual ao nome
                 TEdit(Components[i]).visible := True 
              else
                 TEdit(Components[i]).visible := False;
          end;
    end;
```